# Ignore Markup when searching in SublimeText2

Tags: html, sublimetext2

While working in an HTML document, I want to find and replace all of the < or > symbols with &gt; or &lt;. Is there any way to easily replace the instances of that within content, say in a `<p>` tag, but not have it change the < and > that wrap the tags?

**EDIT:** Here's a quick example.  I'd usually be using this when formatting someone's work (sometimes multiple paragraphs of technical writing) and formatting for HTML.  I'd like to be able to convert the less-than and greater-than symbols into their HTML code without messing up the HTML markup of the page:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <p>I want to convert these characters: < ></p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Greater than: >
        </li>
        <li>
            Less than: <
        </li>
        <li>Images: <img src="test.jpg"><br><img src="test.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are the symbols used? Do you always have a space after them?

Comment: The use of the symbols varies, so it does not always have a space after them, depending on the source document (ie. could be: >5 or > 5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Sublime's Regex mode in its search/replace, and using lookahead/lookbehind assertions to accomplish what you want. I will try to write an example regex and update the answer as soon as it's done, but this should get you started in the exploration of how to accomplish your goal.

**Update:**
This should help you find all instances of `<` that aren't part of normal HTML/XML tags. Entering `<(?!/?\w+>)` into the search field with regex mode turned on should cause it to lock on to any `<` that don't fit the rules for an XML/HTML tag.

The `>` will be harder, if even possible using that method, as lookbehinds don't allow variable length matches. The solution may be to use the first regex to replace the `<` with some character or combination of characters not used in the document, use another regex to swap the `>`, then swap the characters that replaced the initial `<`. I have thought in mind for that as well.

**Another Update:**
This is the approach I would take. It takes multiple steps, but it's simple:

1. Find `(?:<)(\w+)([^<>]*?)(?:>)(.*)(?:<)(/\1)(?:>)` and replace with `@@$1$2@@$3@@$4@@` to reformat tag pairs to protect them from the next steps.
2. Find `(?:<)(\w+)([^<>]*?/)(?:>)` and replace with with `@@$1$2@@`. This will deal with self-terminating tags like `<br/>`. If you have
3. Find `<` and replace with `||`
4. Find `>` and replace with `<`
5. Find `||` and replace with `>`
6. Find `(?:\@\@)(.+?)(?:\@\@)` and replace with `<$1>` to restore tags.

Of course, you can replace the `@@` and `||` with anything you like, just so long as they're not the same and don't occur elsewhere in the document. This approach also will only work if your html is XHTML compliant, specifically all tags must have closing tags, and single tags like `<img>` and `<br>` must be self closed, such as `<img/>` and `<br/>`

Comment: This works until I have to wrap multiple lines in tags, for example the find and replace will not pick up <ul> or <body> tags for the first few steps.  Any idea if there is a workaround for that?

Comment: Aye... That's what I was afraid of.. try using `(?:<)(/?\w+)([^<>]*?)(?:>)` and `@@$1$2@@` for the first step and skipping the second instead.. it doesn't have the tag-matching, but seems to work alright as long as none of your content matches a standard tag--i was trying my best to avoid false positive matches :P you'll just have to look a bit closer at the results to make sure you didn't change or miss anything you didn't mean to.

Comment: Unfortunately, the true best way to deal with this situation would be to write a script that actually parses the html and changes the contents--you essentially need a finite state machine that can recognize what is actually a tag. If that is an agreeable option, I can help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think your second update will save me some time at least.  I figured somebody would have built a plugin that does something like what I was looking for, but I guess not.